# Headphones makes noise when i touch the jack. (MacBook)

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, headphones

I have a MacBook Pro 13" and have plugged the iphone 5 headphone into it. When I touch the jack they make some noise, I doesn't matter how gentle I touch they always make a noise. They seem to fit tight into the jack receiver. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

This noise (assuming it's a buzzing sound) is normal - not a problem. It is just because of the electricity flow you are causing with your finger. It is explained well [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100614193437AAwqy3t).